# JPA - Best way to update entity with multiple one to many associations

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, one-to-many

What is best way to execute update of entity which has multiple one to many associations (>8)?

I tried multiple ways, like using Jpa and hibernate merge, but it first inserts new child entries and then deletes the old ones.I need to check if one of child is changed and if it is then update it, if not do nothing with it.

My objects looks like:

```
public class Parent {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long parentId;

private String attribute;

@OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "parent",
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    orphanRemoval = true
)
private Set<Child1> child1= new HashSet<>();

@OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "parent",
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    orphanRemoval = true
)
private Set<Child2> child2= new HashSet<>();

...
// other associations are removed because they are the same
//Constructors, getters and setters removed for brevity

}

public class Child1{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long child1Id;

private String attribute;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
private Parent parent;

//Constructors, getters and setters removed for brevity

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof PostComment )) return false;
    return this.attribute != null && this.attribute.equals(((Child1) o).getAttribute());
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return 31;
}
}
```

All other childs looks alike, with same many to one association and their attributes.

Every help is welcome! Thanks!